# htaccess force https on specific query param and remove www generally

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

Grateful for some help with this. I am attempting to force https on a certain view identified by a query param in the url. But the rule seems to conflict with other rules that force the removal of the www subdomain.

My .htaccess currently looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)param=(foo)(&|$)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)param=(foo)(&|$)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This, however results in a redirect loop on the page in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `THE_REQUEST` in first 2 rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/index\.php\?param=foo[&\s]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?param=foo[&\s]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache for testing this change.

Comment: That no longer forces https on the page in question. The url i wish to force https on looks like this: http://example.com/index.php?option=foo&view=checkout&lang=en

Comment: Yes - sorry that was intended to be illustrative. i am using the correct parameter in my version of your code. https is still not forced.

Comment: It removes www from all urls. The first forces https to redirect to http if the query parameter is matched. The second does the reverse: forces https to on if it is off and the query param is matched. The third just needs to take any case where there is a www in the url and redirect to not have www preserving the http or https of the original request. My original rules worked independently, but not together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78838/discussion-between-larpo-and-anubhava).